# Ender 3 Pro stopped and not heat up

Tags: creality-ender-3, nozzle

While taking a print today, the Ender 3 Pro suddenly stopped. I tried to restart printing, but the heater cartridge does not heat up. I tested the thermistor and it senses heat. Next, I checked the voltage of the heater cartridge.

I think there is a problem here. Because even if the nozzle is at 0 degrees, it constantly shows 24 V. What is the cause of this problem?

Comment: How are you measuring the "voltage of the heater cartridge"? And you're reading 24 V across it with the nozzle turned off/set to 0 degrees and yet it's not heating up? That would imply two simultaneous failures (of both the cartridge itself and the control circuitry) which seems unlikely.

Comment: I measure the heater cartridge with a multimeter. And yes, despite being 24v, the nozzle does not heat up. As you said, there are faults on both sides. Guess I'll have to spend some money :)

Comment: Yes, of course with a multimeter, but I meant: what points did you measure across? Most 3D printers use low-side switching so you cannot measure from the positive terminal of the heater to any ground point (which will always measure 24 V), you must measure to the specific ground connector for the heater.

Comment: Yes, now I understand. But I'm not good at electronic components. Can you tell me exactly where I should measure?

Comment: Follow the two wires of the heater to the control board. Where they make contact with the control board is where you should measure.

Comment: I'm tried but still the same. There are 3 transistors on the motherboard and the middle one is measuring incorrectly. I think the cause of the problem may be the transistor. I will try to replace it and of course the heater cartridge as well. Thank you very much for your help.